# l'm having trouble to load index page l'm getting an error, while working with MVC in php

Tags: php, model-view-controller

```
    <?php
  /*
   * App Core Class
   * Creates URL & loads core controller
   * URL FORMAT - /controller/method/params
   */
  class Core {
    protected $currentController = 'Pages';
    protected $currentMethod = 'index';
    protected $params = [];

    public function __construct(){
      $url = $this->getUrl();

      // Look in BLL for first value
      if(file_exists('../app/controllers/' . ucwords($url[0]). '.php')){
        // If exists, set as controller
        $this->currentController = ucwords($url[0]);
        // Unset 0 Index
        unset($url[0]);
      }

      // Require the controller
      require_once '../app/controllers/'. $this->currentController . '.php';

      // Instantiate controller class
      $this->currentController = new $this->currentController;

      // Check for second part of url
      if(isset($url[1])){
        // Check to see if method exists in controller
        if(method_exists($this->currentController, $url[1])){
          $this->currentMethod = $url[1];
          // Unset 1 index
          unset($url[1]);
        }
      }

      // Get params
      $this->params = $url ? array_values($url) : [];

      // Call a callback with array of params
      call_user_func_array([$this->currentController, $this->currentMethod], $this->params);
    }

    public function getUrl(){
      if(isset($_GET['url'])){
        $url = rtrim($_GET['url'], '/');
        $url = filter_var($url, FILTER_SANITIZE_URL);
        $url = explode('/', $url);
        return $url;
      }
    }
  }
```

I'm getting the error below

Notice: Trying to access array offset on value of type null in C:\xampp\htdocs\ems\app\libraries\Core.php on line 16
View does not exists

l have search tried to figure it out but nothing is coming through

Comment: It means `$url` is `null`. Which means getUrl()  returned null. Which probably means `if(isset($_GET['url'])){` returned false, and therefore getUrl() didn't execute its `return` statement. If you didn't put `?url=something` on the end of the URL you used to call the view, then that's why that would happen.

Comment: Oh yeah, thanks for the help

Comment: NP. Does that answer the question / solve the problem, then?

Comment: yes it does, thank you